# How can I import a .js file and convert to a JSON file (or Pandas df) in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, json, pandas, twitter

I have downloaded my twitter data archive and have been provided with a .js file. My understanding is that this is a JavaScript file and not a JSON file (is that right?). How do I convert this to a JSON file (so I can then convert it to a Pandas df)? Or how do I import it into Python and convert it to a Pandas df?

I can find posts that describe how to import JSON data and convert it to a Pandas df but haven't found anything on importing .js files.

The file I want to import is called `tweet.js` and I want to import it into a variable called `twitter_data`

---

### UPDATE:

Here is a snapshot of the first few rows of the file, to the end of the first 'tweet' object (I've added indentation for ease of reading but the `\n` are actually included in the string in the .js file):

```
'window.YTD.tweet.part0 = [ {\n  
  "tweet" : {\n    
     "retweeted" : false,\n    
     "source" : "<a href=\\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\\" rel=\\"nofollow\\">Twitter for iPhone</a>",\n    
     "entities" : {\n      
        "hashtags" : [],\n      
        "symbols" : [],\n      
        "user_mentions" : [],\n      
        "urls" : []\n    },\n    
        "display_text_range" : [ "0", "152" ],\n    
        "favorite_count" : "1",\n    
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str" : "1276854543486197760",\n    
        "id_str" : "1277154367104262145",\n    
        "in_reply_to_user_id" : "2735246778",\n    
        "truncated" : false,\n    
        "retweet_count" : "0",\n    
        "id" : "1277154367104262145",\n    
        "in_reply_to_status_id" : "1276854543486197760",\n    
        "created_at" : "Sun Jun 28 08:18:24 +0000 2020",\n    
        "favorited" : false,\n    
        "full_text" : "@ThisUser @thatuser Yesterday I learned how to use pipelines and gridsearch with python",\n    
        "lang" : "en",\n    
        "in_reply_to_screen_name" : "ThisUser",\n   
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str" : "2735246778"\n  }\n},
```

I want to get all the "tweet" objects and for each of those I'm only interested in the "full_text" sub-object.

I have now read in the .js file into my Jupyter Notebook using the following code:

```
with open('tweet.js') as js_file:      
    twitter_data = js_file.read()
```

Now I need to convert it to a dataframe of tweets. I tried running `json.loads(twitter_data)` but this results in the following error:
`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: was there any documentation given when you downloaded the data?

Comment: Does the content look like a valid json object?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best solution, but it would work if you have one `.js` file or multiple files with the same structure.

For example you have this `.js` file:

```
data = """
window.data = [
{"some unimportant things": []},
{"jsonObjectYouNeed": [
    {"text": "hello", "date": "2020-06-28"},
    {"text": "stack", "date": "2020-06-28"},
    {"text": "overflow", "date": "2020-06-28"}
]
}]
"""
```

You can exctract JSON object from js file using python string processing methods: `.partition`, slicing and all others that you can find in [string methods documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods):

```py
parts = data.partition('{"jsonObjectYouNeed')
json_data = parts[1] + parts[2]
json_data = json_data[:-2]
```

Then you can convert it into python object using `json.loads` and load it to the `pd.DataFrame`:

```py
import json

data = json.loads(json_data)['jsonObjectYouNeed']
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

df
```

Result:

```
    text        date
0   hello       2020-06-28
1   stack       2020-06-28
2   overflow    2020-06-28
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I import a .js file rather than replicate one by typing the data into a code cell as in your example? I'm assuming pd.read_csv() won't work?

Comment: you can open it as a text file: `with open('some_file.js') as js_file:` `data = js_file.read()`

Comment: Thanks ZTEP. I have now read in the .js file into my Jupyter Notebook using the following code: `with open('tweet.js') as js_file: 
    twitter_data = js_file.read()`. Now I need to convert it to a dataframe of tweets but running `json.loads(twitter_data)` results in the following error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Yeah, now you have to select valid JSON object from your .js file using python string processing methods.  I don't see any array in the example from original post, so I can't help you with this selection

Comment: Again, I mentioned that this is not very good solution, maybe there are solution to select JSON objects from .js files, but I am not familiar with this